# Constexpr cast from const char* to const unsigned char* (uint8_t)

Tags: c++, casting, constexpr

My intent is to just have a pointer to an arbitrary array of bytes (uint8_t), whether that be from a C-style string (which is really just an array of bytes) or from an initializer list.

Consider the following class I am trying to get to work:

```
class Test {
public:
    constexpr Test(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> list):
        _size(list.size()),
        _data(std::data(list))
     {
    
     }

    constexpr Test(std::string_view str):
        _size(str.size()),
        _data(str.data())
    {

    }

    constexpr const uint8_t* data() const { return _data; }

private:
    size_t _size;
    const uint8_t* _data;
};
```

The problem is, the `data()` from std::string_view is of type `const char*` but `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`.

I cannot use `reinterpret_cast` because this is a constexpr.

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Not the problem but your `intializer_list` constructor is going to lead to undefined behavior.  ``intializer_list` wraps a temporary array and when the constructor ends so dose the lifetime of the array.  That will leave you with a dangling pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Woops, I didn't realize that.  My intent was to accept some sort of array of bytes so I could do Test({1,2,3,4,5}) where the array is statically/constexpr allocated data.

Comment: You don't actually need constexpr over here. Class are natively designed to be used at compile time. Compile time string algorithm generally have some sance in case of some `url resource("https://stackoverflow.com");` so that you can parse URL to parts in compile time. Otherwise this is nonce, and all what you need is just inline and reinterpret cast.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::array<uint8_t, size> buf{...};` instead of `Test`? Or `template <std::size_t size> Test(uint8_t (&buf)[size]);`. But `const uint8_t t[] = "foo"; Test test(t);` seems less than ideal. Having `const uint8_t* _data;` does not work with passing in the array as rvalue.

Comment: Please clarify how you intend to use this class. What you are describing seems weird. For example `Test({1,2,3,4,5})` also can't really make sense, since it is essentially trying to form a pointer to a temporary object. It is not clear to me how the `constexpr` requirement comes in or why you need this pointer class.

Comment: Anyway, there is no way to reinterpret a `char` as a `unsigned char` in a constant expression currently. You can only convert between the two. So choose only one of the types or convert everything to a common type, for example using `std::array` as suggested above.